# Compiling C# + WPF on Linux in order to run on Windows

Tags: c#, wpf, linux, compilation

I have a C# application of which some parts are written using WPF (which is not supported by Mono). Is it possible to compile this application on Linux? Ultimately, the application will run on Windows, but it is part of a larger framework and our entire build process runs on Linux, so I would like to be able to compile the C# application on Linux as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mono does not, and currently has no plans to support WPF, and by proxy, XAML. Where you might get a break with a subset of XAML is with Silverlight support via Moonlight.  See http://www.mono-project.com/WPF for details.

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely not possible, Mono lacks the build step that will compile your XAML to a binary format and embed it

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is NO for the moment.

The same question was asked here:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/kirtan007/1516/Default.aspx

Look at the last answer in this thread (a little bit of hope):

http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread161098.html

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other answers, natively this doesn't seem possible.

If you have the appropriate licenses already you could look into running [VMWare](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/) or [Virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) to build it. Obviously memory usage and time requirements for the build will go up, it all depends on how much it matters to you that you can run it all on one box. I believe both support scripting.