# compile c# on linux with wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, linux, compilation

Ok, so read my question before you respond. I have a c# project that I need to compile on linux that contains WPF. I don't need to run WPF on linux, just need to compile. WPF is essentially just .net DLL's, so you think this would be doable since I'm NOT trying to run the app on linux, just build it. As far as I know I can't do this with mono compile, but I may be wrong. Maybe I can use the Microsoft compiler somehow? I don't know.

Any ideas on how I could JUST BUILD a C# app on Linux(again, I don't need to run it).

Comment: Lol why is there always some dude that rolls through and downvotes questions.

Comment: Automated build process. Have a team and we are working with nant to create an automated build process for nightly's and releases. Why would you ask why I would want to compile from the command line? Windows severs are more expensive.

Comment: @sarnold if it's possible to use mono to build c# apps that have wpf, that's an answer, from all I read it said it wasn't possible. If it is, then that's an answer that I'd accept(I'm running the latest mono).

Comment: It is possible theoretically by mocking assemblies... But I should try to implement it this evening...

Comment: In my experience, if you're doing Windows development and try to save money by not using Windows, you'll waste a lot more money on the extra time and effort it takes you to get things to work. Just use a Windows box for your automated builds.

Comment: @Carson63000 not on open source projects :p...not making/spending money to make it work...server still costs the same amount each month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible: http://www.mono-project.com/WPF

Comment: To summarize, WPF is a huge API, and as yet no one is willing to implement.

Comment: I'm not trying to run WPF, just to compile. Heard there was a way using some MSIL and mono or something?

Comment: I started the project I am working on in Linux, Mono is the only set of libraries for .NET that I could find.  You can't build the application without the libraries.  Since WPF isn't implemented for Linux, you don't have the libraries.  That and a few other reasons is why I moved my project to Windows and Visual Studio.   Finally, this question was asked and answered here quite some time ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580000/compiling-c-sharp-wpf-on-linux-in-order-to-run-on-windows

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the simplest solution I could imagine: copy the Microsoft versions of the required assemblies (like PresentationCore.dll and PresentationFramework.dll) to a Linux box and build a simple WPF application using them.

This didn't work. I got lots of warnings about various assemblies like:

> Reference 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' not resolved
>   Found a conflict between : 'System' and 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. Using 'System' reference.

And there was the error:

> CS0584: Internal compiler error: Could not import type `System.Windows.Window' from `PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

There was also one other error, but it's probably just a consequence of this error.

Based on this, I think building WPF applications using mono will not be simple, if possible at all.