# Compile WPF .NET Core on wine to run on windows?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, .net-6.0, wine

So since the [existing questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9865346/compile-c-sharp-on-linux-with-wpf) about this only talk about .Net Framework (obviously, they're old), I thought I'd try to find out if I can compile my WPF .NET 6 application on wine to run on windows.

My immediate problem is that I'd like to avoid trying to setup a windows gitlab runner (no free windows VMs or docker containers for devs) by just compiling via wine. I'll definitely run this on windows, as this a client application, but I'd also like to build it in my CI pipeline, which seems to require a windows server for WPF.

Comment: https://blog.mi.hdm-stuttgart.de/index.php/2020/02/29/attempts-at-automating-the-build-process-of-a-net-wpf-application-with-gitlabs-ci-cd-pipeline/

Answer (score 1):

> compiling via wine

You do not need to do that, .Net Core can fully compile under any operating system. You can either do a normal framework compilation or a targeted self-contained compilation for any of the supported OSs.

Also all of this is supported out of the box with GitHub actions, it uses the required Docker runtime to build your artifacts and publishes them for you. Presumably GitLab should also do that.

Comment: This works for most of .Net Core and ASP.Net Core, but unfortunately not WinForms and WPF. Those will fail with `NETSDK1100: Windows is required to build Windows desktop applications`.

Comment: Note that [this](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/pull/25358) SDK commit allows exactly what you want with the added `<EnableWindowsTargeting>` project tag.

Comment: Oh this is great, thanks for pulling that out of your hat. Looking forward to 6.0.4 then, will get back to this thread once it's out and I can test it :)